# How to maintain function parameter spacing when listing as a single column

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is a non-conventional question but it has been bothering me for some time.
Working in C++, oftentimes I am called 6+ parameters to a function and prefer to put them in a staggered configuration to avoid the line going so far to the right that it is no longer in scope.

As an example:

```
void someFunction( int t,
                   int c,
                   float sampleInput,
                   float sampleInput2,
                   double sampleInput3,
                   double sampleInput4,
                   double sampleInput5)
{};
```

Now, when I goto commit my code to git, or sometimes just reopening the doc, or moving to a different IDE causes the function to look something like this:

```
void someFunction( int t,
    int c,
    float sampleInput,
    float sampleInput2,
    double sampleInput3,
    double sampleInput4,
    double sampleInput5)
{};
```

or like this....

```
void someFunction( int t,
          int c,
                        float sampleInput,
      float sampleInput2,
           double sampleInput3,
                                double sampleInput4,
                double sampleInput5)
{};
```

... you get the point. Is there anything I can do to maintain the function parameters in this single column convention without uploading to GIT and seeing the ugly messed up configuration?

Comment: Are you using tab characters for indentation?

Comment: What are you using to format your code? Hopefully, you're not doing this by hand. Take a look at clang-format for example.

Comment: tabs or spaces, I've noticed that can make a difference. However, ultimately they both seem to revert to one of the configuration shown above

Comment: @cigien I use visual studio?

Comment: No problem, there is a clang-format plugin for VS I'm sure. Just google it. VS also probably has its own formatter as well.

Comment: @cigien Ok ill look into it, im new to clang-format had not heard of it before. Thank you.

Comment: Try to use less input arguments :)

Comment: Consider placing the arguments into a `struct` and passing the `struct`.

Comment: Visual Studio has its own formatting builtin to the IDE which at times conflicts with formatting plugins. What I mean by that is you click on the button to format then if you don't escape from the code VS puts the format back to its format.

Comment: I got the same issue.  Emacs formats the way you like, Visual Studio indents to the first indentation (tab) position.  I still haven't figured out how to tell VS to format the same way that Emacs does.

Comment: There are options in the settings where you can have VS use spaces instead of tabs. The setting is in Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Tabs